# buildozer debug error when I tried to build apk

Tags: python-3.x, buildozer

[Here are the error log I have been shown when I tried to use buildozer on my ubuntu 64 bit. I used python3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKcRG.png)

Help me please! Thanks.

/home/mukubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 5 more

## Command failed: /home/mukubuntu/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the proper JDK and then setting the alternatives for it:

Install JDK 8:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y
```

Change the JDK version manually:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

From here select the JDK version you want and then try your build again. Hopefully, that will work. You should be able to install more than one version of Java and just select the proper version for doing your builds.